# Difference between setOf and hashSetOf in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What the difference between `setOfStrings` and `hashSetOfStrings` produced by following code snippet?

```
val setOfStrings = setOf("A", "B", "C")
val hashSetOfStrings = hashSetOf("A", "B", "C")
```

Do they always have the same type? The same performance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most important difference between them is **mutability**.

`setOf()` returns an object which implements the `Set` interface, but is probably immutable (not implementing the `MutableSet` subinterface), and so can't be changed.

(The online [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/set-of.html) specify that it's `read-only`, which doesn't *necessarily* mean immutable.  But it's safest to assume so.)

It doesn't specify the concrete type; this is probably to allow it to be changed in future to improve performance, memory usage, and/or similar.  Even now, it could return a `kotlin.collections.EmptySet`, `java.util.Collections.SingletonSet`, or a `kotlin.collections.LinkedHashSet`; the latter has faster (and predictable) iteration compared to a standard `HashSet`.

So `setOf()` is for when you want an efficient, immutable set and don't care about the exact type.

[`hashSetOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/hash-set-of.html), on the other hand, always returns a `kotlin.collections.HashSet` (or a subclass), which is always mutable.  That's for when you need that particular type.

And if you want a mutable set but don't care about the exact type, you're best off calling [`mutableSetOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-set-of.html).

(In general, of course, it's best not to specify concrete types when you don't really need to; that keeps your code flexible.)

Answer (score 7):

There are a few differences.

First, and most importantly, with `setOf` you are telling Kotlin - "I want a set, you go figure out what kind, I don't have a preference". But with `hashSetOf` you are telling Kotlin that you want a `HashSet` specifically.

Second, `setOf` will create a read-only set, whereas `hashSetOf` will create a `HashSet`, which implements `MutableSet`, allowing writes. (Under the covers, ultimately `setOf` gives you a `LinkedHashSet` typed as a `Set` so it is read-only) .

As for `setOfStrings`, it is type `Set<String>` (read-only, backed by `LinkedHashSet`) whereas `hashSetOfStrings` is `HashSet<String>` (read/write, backed by `HashSet`).

Adding the types in might make this more clear:

```
val setOfStrings: Set<String> = setOf("A", "B", "C")
val hashSetOfStrings: HashSet<String> = hashSetOf("A", "B", "C")
```

Comment: Hey i overlooked the read-only set, maybe its usefull to mention the iteration stuff. Than i could remove my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

setOf creates a LinkedHashSet while hashSetOf creates a HashSet.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-linked-hash-set/index.html

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-set/index.html

At the end both are MutableSets - but setOf casts to read-only Set

The difference comes with iteration.
The first LinkedHashSet is iterated in the way you store the data (that the Linked stands for) see also https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/set-of.html

The HashSet stores the data according to the hash. So in that case iteration is more randomly. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-set/index.html

So if order for iteration matters, than choose setOf or linkedSetOf otherwise you could also choose hashSetOf